# app-sidebar-nav's navItems is not updating

Tags: angular, core-ui

I would like to update badge of sidebar navigation of core ui angular but unfortunately variable value is updating but does not updating sidebar navigation.

I am using below line.

```
<app-sidebar-nav [navItems]="navItems" [perfectScrollbar] [disabled]="appSidebar.minimized"></app-sidebar-nav>
```

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

`navItems` is an array of objects. If you update any of its fields, you'll have to let Angular know it has changed. Objects are a reference type in js. 
Deep clone of `navItems` is the way to go.

See also: https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-angular-admin-template/issues/180